# How should I code a laboratory variable that may occasionally have "under X.XX" type of character data as a continuous numeric variable?

Tags: continuous-data, censoring

A typical laboratory in my region may give a result to e.g. the C-reactive protein (CRP) blood test in the following way (I'll omit the units here):

1. if the result is under <10, they'll give the result as "<10"
2. in all other cases, they'll give a (continuous) numeric answer

Let's say I want to treat that variable (CRP) as a continuous numeric variable for e.g. regression analysis.

What is the most customary way to code those (statistically speaking) pesky "<10" results as numeric? I do understand that some kind of compromise is needed, but what might be the most usual approach?

I use R for data analysis, if it's of relevance.

Comment: Your data are [censored](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censoring_%28statistics%29#Types). **1**. There's standard approaches for dealing with censored responses (try a site search here, or see the linked article). $\,$ **2**. In the case where it's a predictor rather than a response variable, I'd suggest a 0-1 variable (perhaps called "censored") to indicate the "<10" (censored value, coded to 1) or "10+" (0) and then a separate column for the actual recorded values that are 10 or more. ... ctd

Comment: ctd... In that second column you might choose to make the value recorded for censored data 10, or you might make it 0 (or indeed other choices are possible) - which you choose will (naturally) affect how you interpret the coefficient of the binary censored indicator. For recording it as "0" you'd interpret the coefficient as the average effect (on the response) of the censored values. For "1" you'd interpret it as the average amount by which it's shifted from the threshold value (10).

Comment: @Glen_b, thank you very much for this explanation. I'm baffled that this question is not tackled more in the most basic courses of (bio-)statistics - this is a very common scenario, at least in medicine.

To approach this in R, I now think I should use tobit {AER} or {censReg} in R. I'm afraid I might need further help with these, but I guess specific questions about those should be asked elsewhere, maybe on Stack Overflow or RStudio Community?

Comment: If the question is primarily coding related, yes. If there's statistical content to the questions, they should fit here. However, if I understand correctly those packages are for censored response variables (in which case, there's also the `survival` package that comes with R, and various other survival-related packages, some of which should handle left-censoring). If your censored variable is a predictor (IV) I don't think those will be likely to help.

Comment: @Glen_b, I think you already answered my most pressing question: as my left-censored variable is a regressor, R package solutions such as tobit() {AER} and {censReg} won't help me. I think I'll look into the R package {imputeLCMD} and try and approach the dilemma through left-censored missing data imputation.